# Is there any danger in require '/../private' in PHP?

Tags: php, security

I have a required config file outside of /public_html
So I retrieve it like so:

```
define('FILE_PATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );
require(FILE_PATH . '../private/config.php');
```

I'm using PHP 5.4
Is there any security concerns in doing this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is fine as long as you don’t base parts of the path on unvalidated user inputs.